# split returns a string in place of string array

Tags: java, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

Whenever I try to read a string in java and split it to get an array of strings by using `String[] part=str.split(" ")`,it returns a single array in place of returning an array of strings i.e., part. `length=1` and thus when accessed gives out an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

here is the code I am working on currently:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    InputReader in = new InputReader(System.in);
    String s=in.readString();
    String[] str=s.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        System.out.println(str[i]);
}
private static class InputReader
{
    private InputStream stream;
    private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private int curChar;
    private int numChars;
    private SpaceCharFilter filter;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public int read()
    {
        if (numChars == -1)
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        if (curChar >= numChars)
        {
            curChar = 0;
            try
            {
                numChars = stream.read(buf);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            if (numChars <= 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return buf[curChar++];
    }

    public int readInt()
    {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-')
        {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        int res = 0;
        do
        {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public String readString()
    {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res.toString();
    }
    public double readDouble() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        double res = 0;
        while (!isSpaceChar(c) && c != '.') {
            if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
                return res * Math.pow(10, readInt());
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        }
        if (c == '.') {
            c = read();
            double m = 1;
            while (!isSpaceChar(c)) {
                if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
                    return res * Math.pow(10, readInt());
                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                m /= 10;
                res += (c - '0') * m;
                c = read();
            }
        }
        return res * sgn;
    }
    public long readLong() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        long res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }
    public boolean isSpaceChar(int c)
    {
        if (filter != null)
            return filter.isSpaceChar(c);
        return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
    }

    public String next()
    {
        return readString();
    }

    public interface SpaceCharFilter
    {
        public boolean isSpaceChar(int ch);
    }
   }
}
```

For example , whenever I write "hello I am here" it must print "hello" , "I" ,"am" and "here" in 4 separate lines ideally rather in my case it prints only "hello" .

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: your code please

Comment: what string do ypu want to split?

Comment: Please clarify whether it's returning a String, or a String array of size 1 with the original string as the only element of the array.

Comment: we need to see the string.......

Comment: String s=in.readString();
        String[] str=s.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
         System.out.println(str[i]);

Comment: @kunjalrupala edit your own post, _don't_ post it within comments.

Comment: but what is the value inside s ?

Comment: Please provide an example string.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot.Please have a look at it

Comment: I personally can't, work blocks the imgur site. Generally better to actually put in the actual information, without putting it in a picture.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error given the posted code.

Comment: here i have attached my whole code along with the input reader class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readString` method is just reading up to a space, that is, just the next word - here respective part from your code (thsi is NOT a solution, just copy&paste from the code that is not working):

> ```
> public String readString()
> {
>     ...  // ignore spaces at start
>     do
>     {
>         res.appendCodePoint(c);
>         c = read();
>     } while (!isSpaceChar(c));  // STOPS reading if it got a space
>     return res.toString();
> }
> ```

no need to call split since `InputReader` is already doing the job.

But is `InputReader` really needed? Have a look at the `Scanner` class.

Comment: that doesn't solve his problem I tested  also keep getting only hello as output

Comment: @MohammadOghli "that" what? the code I posted is just the part (as posted in the question) that is causing the problem - it is just to show what is going wrong - and seems (by his comment) that using the `Sacnner` as I indicated in the last sentence, **SOLVED** the problem! sorry that I found the error before you figured it out...

Comment: @MohammadOghli I updated the answer to clarify that the posted code is just a quote of the original code showing the defective part!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and there are not problems with it. We can guess that problem with string "s" because "split" works well.
When there are not symbols " " in your string "s" you will have a single element in "str", don't array.

For example, you can choose the code to discover your problem:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class ReadFileTxt {

    static File fileName;
    static ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public ReadFileTxt() {
        readFile();
    }

    public static void readFile() {
        String str;
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setVisible(true);
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fileName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            str = reader.readLine();
            while (str != null) {

                // Delete redundant blanks
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    str = str.replace("  ", " ");
                }
                String[] strMas = str.split(" ");
                data.add(strMas);
                str = reader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReadFileTxt();
    }
}
```

The txt file for it:

```
1                      XXXXXXXX                  12342
2                      YYYYYYY                    45321
3                      ZZZZZZZZZ               5454532
```

Comment: I have attached a screenshot please have a look at it .

Comment: Since your code, it looks like the method "readString()" have to convert context of "in" in string. I think it can be here problem. I need to check it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your program code I test it and it returns exactly the results you want

I think the problem with this line when reading the string `s`:

```
String s = in.readLine();
```

you can test this [code](https://ideone.com/rRR4OM) and see the output:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    String[] str = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){ 
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
```

**Update:**

I test your `InputReader` class methods and found that problem with this method `readString()` it only read single string in the line and ignore all strings after space character:

```
    InputReader in = new InputReader(System.in);
    String s = in.readString();
    System.out.println(s);
```

if you test this code on string `"hello I am here"` it will return only `hello` so you should fix the problem with readString method to get the correct output.

Check this `readString()` new implementation to fix your problem it worked perfectly:

```
public String readString()
{
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        } while (c != '\n'); // stop reading at the end of line
        return res.toString();
}
```

Comment: When i try with scanner or bufferedreader it gives correct output but when I  use FastIO as the method for taking input it gives out the error .I have even attached the snapshot of it along with the whole code.Try to paste my code and check in your editor.

Comment: @kunjalrupala  check my new code implementation of your `readString()` in my updated answer it worked perfect for your case.